# Jackson - Custom Deserializer is never called

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a class that needs to be deserialized from a JSON response. Since the response contains a String value for one of the fields and I need it as an int, I implemented a custom deserializer

The class is

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = JsonFilterPositionDeserializer.class)
public class FilterPosition implements Comparable<FilterPosition>, Serializable {
    public int section = 0;
    public int row = 0;
    public int index = 0;

    //...getters and methods
}
```

This is my custom deserializer

```
public class JsonFilterPositionDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<FilterPosition> {
    @Override
    public FilterPosition deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        int row = node.get("row").getIntValue();
        int index = node.get("index").getIntValue();
        String section = node.get("section").asText();

        //Do stuff to transform section to int

        return new FilterPosition(sectionNum, row, index);
    }
}
```

And this is the class that has the `FilterPosition` field

```
public class Filter implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private FilterPosition position;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

The problem is, the custom deserializer method never gets called. Jackson always tries to deserialize it normally, which ends up throwing an exception when trying to cast a String to int. I've even debugged it and it's calling the default constructor of `FilterPosition`, the `_nonStandardCreation` variable of `BeanDeserializer` for that class is false.

Is there anything I'm missing? Do I have to mark the field in the `Filter` class with an annotation so the custom deserializer gets called?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you post the exception stack trace and the JSON data you're trying to deserialize?

Comment: And as importantly, actual code that shows what you are doing. A common gotcha is trying to deserialize a `List` or `Map`, without passing parameterization.

Comment: Same problem happening to me. Were you able to come with a solution?

Comment: @RedEagle No, I ended up modifying the setter so the received string is parsed by my own code and correctly converted to int; same with the getter. Not the tidiest solution but it's been working well for almost a year

Comment: Thought that would be the case. I've implemented a custom serializer that does the trick. Not the cleanest solution but it works!